# How to get import google maps?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to pass project from the eclips to Android Studio

All went well except the google maps dependency, and I can not understand what is the problem, I have already found a lot of topics about this issue, but most of them suggest to add google-play-services as a lib to the project.

I found this lib in my sdk under the 'user' folder, made the jar, but studio told my that it can't to recognize this jar...

So, I am in the stuck, what I can do?

There is imports that are not resolved

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
```

there is my `build-gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myappid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.41.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.41.jar')
compile files('libs/SekindoAndroidSdk.jar')
compile files('libs/verdatasdk.jar')
compile files('libs/wheel.jar')
}
```

Google services instaled

[image]

If I forgot about something, fell free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your gradle `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'` and check if you have installed Google Play services in Android SDK Manager.

Remove all your maps imports and add these:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
```

Edit:

The reason that these imports are not found is that google maps v1 is no longer in use and you should move to v2 but if you must use v1 you can try downloading jar file and importing it to android studio. link to v1 - [Google Maps v1 Jar](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi11jar.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not help. But this `MapView` class was found here `import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;`  there is new `.gsm` word

Comment: Edited the answer, try chaning to maps 11.+ and add imports above

Comment: I have already tried this. I need these imports (GeoPoint, ItemizedOverlay, MapActivity and so on according to my question), but there are no such dependency under `.gms.maps.` . What I am thinking about now its, that `android.maps` it was old style of map dependency, modern is `android.gsm.maps`, but under the `.gsm` there is no such files that was in previous version ... So, I need to understand how to use old dependency? Maybe I need to download old sdk?

Comment: The reason that these imports are not found is that google maps v1 is no longer in use and you should move to v2 but if you must use v1 you can try downloading jar file and importing it to android studio. link to v1 below - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi11jar.htm

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I need to solve this issue. Could you please add this to the answer